# 4 month old 500 GB SATA HDD making noise?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

My 4 month old 500 GB SATA HDD making noise sometimes and the PC hangs when it makes noise when the noise stops desktop work fine.

It doesn't happen every day but it does happen.

Is something wrong with HDD, Data, power cable, or my cabinet's power supply? Should I run scandisk or defragmentation on the disk.

Answer (score 4):

Defragmentation increases load on the disk in the short term. I would recommend against it. Back up your data *now*, and run a SMART test on the disk in question. Get the utility from the manufacturer of your disk (for example, Seagate's utility is called SeaTools), and use it to run a SMART test on the disk. If the SMART test reports imminent failure, replace the disk.

Your power supply and cabling are almost certainly *not* to blame.

Answer (score 1):

If the sound is like your computer is reading a lot from the disk than it could be that the disk is fragmented. If it produces "metal" sound then most likely the disk is dying.

If I were you I would first make a copy of the data on the disk and than run scandisk + defrag. If scandisk finds bad sectors or defragmentation doesn't help I would return the disk to your supplier.

Comment: should i run scandisk and defrag after taking backup of data? can i run without backing up data

Comment: and is there is any possibility of Power supply problem. like power supply not giving enough power to HDD

Comment: I would make a backup as soon as possible. scandisk and defragmentation won't make any damage to your data, but you never know if the disk won't die during the process. If the HDD is making noise I don't think the problem is with power supply.

Comment: Check http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/ Scroll down to Hard disk tools. Maybe you can use some of those tools. Check also the web site of the drive manufacturer. Maybe they have some diagnostic tools for download.

Comment: @Jitendra: You can upvote suggestions; hover your mouse over the suggestion and you will see upvote and flag controls to the left. Upvote the ones you like to reward the suggestors with reputation increases.

Answer (score 0):

- Backup data ASAP .
- You should    prepare yourself that
  exist high    probability that disk
  is dying.

Answer (score 0):

There is HIGH chance your disk is dying so backup your data. Then see whether your power supply is handling the load correctly by switching your power supply.